# Trying to add a warning system to my mongodb, it works but says application didn't respond

Tags: discord.js

```
const {Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");
const db = require("../../Structures/Schemas/InfractionDB");

module.exports = {
    name: "warnings",
    description: "Give a warning",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    options: [
                {
                    name: "target",
                    description: "Select a target.",
                    type: "USER",
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    name: "reason",
                    description: "Provide a reason.",
                    type: "STRING",
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    name: "evidence",
                    description: "Provide evidence.",
                    type: "STRING",
                    required: false
                },
            ],
        
    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     * @param {Client} client 
     */
    execute(interaction, client) {
        const{guild, member, options} = interaction
        const Target = options.getMember("target");
        const Reason = options.getString("reason");
        const Evidence = options.getString("evidence") || "None provided";

        const Response = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setAuthor({name: "MOD BOT", iconURL: guild.iconURL()});

            db.findOne({GuildID: guild.id, UserID: Target.id}, async (err,data)=> {
                if(err) throw err;
                if(!data || !data.WarnData) {
                    data = new db({
                        GuildID: guild.id,
                        UserID: Target.id,
                        WarnData: [
                            {
                                ExecuterID: member.id,
                                ExecuterTag: member.user.tag,
                                TargetID: Target.id,
                                TargetTag: Target.user.tag,
                                Reason: Reason,
                                Evidence: Evidence,
                                Date: parseInt(interaction.createdTimestamp / 1000)
                            }
                        ],
                    })
                } else {
                    const WarnDataObject ={
                        ExecuterID: member.id,
                        ExecuterTag: member.user.tag,
                        TargetID: Target.id,
                        TargetTag: Target.user.tag,
                        Reason: Reason,
                        Evidence: Evidence,
                        Date: parseInt(interaction.createdTimestamp / 1000)
                    }
                    data.WarnData.push(WarnDataObject)
                }
                data.save()
            });
            Response.setDescription(`Warning Added: ${Target.user.tag} | ||${Target.id}||\n**Reason**: ${Reason}\n**Evidence**:${Evidence}`);
            guild.channels.cache.get("946217387336818699").send({embeds:[Response]});   
            
}}
```

originally this was routed to a different collection in my db. I've tried to convert it so I can see everything in one place. but it's taken me hours and don't seem to be getting anywhere. Like I said, the data is being stored on the db, but the Response is failing. Any ideas how to fix this? There are no errors in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error i think is that your application is taking too long to respond.
you have only 3 seconds to respose.
for this i would suggest that you execute you interaction as a async function
and you should use await before trying to find it in the database. because it can take some time to find the data in the database.
The data is store in database because it has no concern with the response time but the discord api wants a reply in 3 seconds or it will fail.

I have read your code. it seems okay.
i would suggest you to use the easier way instead of using the object or json form to create the commands.

SlashCommandBuilder from @discordjs/builders

its easy to use and simple.

here is an example of how easy it is if you use SlashCommandBuilder

```
    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('gif')
    .setDescription('Sends a random gif!')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('category')
            .setDescription('The gif category')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoice('Funny', 'gif_funny')
            .addChoice('Meme', 'gif_meme')
            .addChoice('Movie', 'gif_movie'));
```

you can install all the dependencies using

```
npm install discord.js @discordjs/rest discord-api-types
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, I figured this may be the issue. I actually rewrote the entire command because I literally spent hours trying to fix it, I used a similar function and will add some complexity in the near future. That package looks very useful, however I would most likely need to rewrite most of the bot I've created so far to accommodate it.